# STM32 - developing code without controller

Tags: stm32, simulation, code

Is it possible to develop a code for STM32 (hobbyist) without controller attached and test it? Is there a simulator mode or some other possibility? I do not have enough space to let the project "unpacked" and "fixed costs" of assembling and disassembling would take most of the dedicated time.

I am using CubeMX and TrueStudio to develop (or at least I am trying.)

Comment: Simulators are rather limited in real circuits due to all the various hardware you can attach unless you only want to work with the logic in the device and maybe a serial output and GPIO. You can buy  Nucleo-32 and just plug it in via the USB.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Keil simulator for testing your code and seeing how registers work but there are some differences to reality for example for usart simulation baud rates don't make a change but they sure make a change in reality. you can also use the new version of proteus but it only covers a limited number of stm32 microcontrollers